# JVM Hot Swap best practices while debugging

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, remote-debugging

I am spending a lot of time in the debugger while maintaining a legacy project.  The start time for the app is very long, I cannot afford to wait for the program to restart every time I test new changes, so I'm making extensive use of JVM's hot-swap capabilities. The problem I am facing is there is a limited range of operations that the hot swap allows me to perform.  I can modify the body of a method but cannot add additional methods.  Are there any best practices available for using the hot swap capabilities to the maximum?  The ability to modify the body of a method is great but is it somehow possible to get around some of the existing limitations (for example, to be able to add new fields).  I know it's explicitly not supported but maybe it's possible to do it indirectly somehow

Answer (score 2):

I've used [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) for this with some success.

Answer (score 0):

Am guessing you are using HotSwap in combination with [DCEVM](http://hotswapagent.org/mydoc_quickstart.html)? It extends some of the native features of HotSwap(specifics at link) so if you are not using it that'll be your best shot at increasing the scope/features. Sure you can get JRebel if your budget allows but I've found a combination of HotSwap and DCEVM adequate.